# How to share private local git server with any OS

Tags: windows, git, debian, repository

I've configure my first private git server because my projects are growing and I need a source control here.
By the way the server is ok, I don't want to use any third party packages i'm using only git-core on Debian O.S. and it's perfect.

The problem is that I can't configure the terminal O.S. 
I mean that I have a laptop with Windows and another bounch of terminals with Linux and OSX.
The terminals with linux are ready, it's very simple with shell just use git clone and it's done. Same thing for OSx-based laptop

The problem comes with Windows because I don't know how to connect Windows O.S. to the git server. Windows terminal should use **[sourcetree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/)** because that's great!

For now the server has this configuration:

1. One user called *Git* that has root access
2. NO SSH (it's local and **At the moment** I don't need ssh auth)
3. *Git* user has a folder *repos/git/[projects.git]*

That's all. I hope some one know how to connect Windows with my local server.

PS: on Windows I've git, putty and sourcetree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to open http access to your GIT server. Please, [follow this manual](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Public-Access).

Comment: @ClaudioLudovicoPanetta Could you provide any details?